# scipys quadrature function complains about perfectly sane lambda?

Tags: python, math, scipy, integral, scientific-computing

I have 2 versions of a snippet one works one doesn't, this works:

```
f = lambda x : x * 2.0 * pi
print(scipy.integrate.quadrature(f, 0.0, 1.0))
```

This fails:

```
f = lambda x : math.exp(x * 2.0 * pi)`
print(scipy.integrate.quadrature(f, 0.0, 1.0))
```

With error:

```
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

I don;t understand both are scalar functions, why is one accepted but the other is not?

Comment: Just switch to `numpy.exp` to accept an array of x-values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may have intended your functions to operate on scalars, but unless you pass `vec_func=False`, `scipy.integrate.quadrature` will assume your functions can safely take and operate elementwise over arrays.

As it happens, your first `f` can indeed handle arrays, even though you didn't intend it to. Your second `f` uses `math.exp`, which only handles scalars.